# MVC5 foreach loop change class based on SQL field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'am learning MVC5 & Entity Framework 6, and have accomplished a connection to a SQL Database.

I need to change the class of the `<tr>` field based on the TicketStatus.StatusID result

For Example If the StatusID =1 then use:
 `<tr class="ticket even status-new priority-low">`

if the statusID = 2 then use:
`<tr class="ticket even status-open priority-low">`

Etc.. Etc..

This is the current Foreach loop code I have based on the number fields to display in a Bootstrap table.

```
   @foreach (var item in Model)
                {

                    <tr class="ticket even status-new priority-low">

                        <td class="status"><span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketStatus.Status)</span></td>
                        <td class="number"><ul class="user-dashboard-tickets"><li class="user-dashboard-tickets"><a href="#"><span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketID)</span></a></li></ul></td>
                        <td class="assigned">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketOwner.OwnerName)</td>
                        <td class="title"><h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</h2></td>
                        <td class="type">Problem</td>
                        <td class="assigned">test.user</td>
                        <td class="age">2 days</td>

                    </tr>

                }
```

I don't know if you can put another foreach loop inside the loop? or add a query to the `<tr>` field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can put any code inside Razor view, even inside a loop, like this:

```
var statusClass = "";
switch (TicketStatus.StatusID){
 case 1:
     statusClass = "status-open";
     break;
}

<tr class="ticket even @statusClass priority-low">
```